# Is there any way to use BigQuery mirroring Firebase Firestore only for CREATE and DELETE only?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

I know I could perfectly make a query to filter only CREATEs and DELETEs from BigQuery. But, Firebase charges for every read from Firestore. So my idea is to save some money getting a changelog only for CREATEs and DELETEs.

I have some collections that I want to monitor in BigQuery that has updates every 5 minutes. But I'm only interested in tracking how many are there.

What I want is to know the growth and churn rates of these entities on my database without wasting unnecessary reads.

Any thoughts?

Comment: According to the official documentation [Export Collections to BigQuer](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-bigquery-export), you can "Generate schema views" to create views that make it easier to query relevant data.

Comment: Hi @marian.vladoi, I know I can make views or queries in BigQuery to get the info that I need. The thing is not to mirror UPDATES because it will take a read from Firestore that I'm not interested in. Thanks anyway.